# Cursor in android studio for Mac is rectangle area

Tags: android, macos

[image: image description here]

The editor keeps in inserting mode, I cannot change to the mode in "|". Two ways from the Internet have been tried, uncheck the "use block caret" and Fn+enter. Fn+i can change once for a file, but when I open another file, it still keeps in inserting mode with a rectangle area.

Answer (score 6):

You should have seen this when there is a Vim option enabled in your Android studio IDE. To resolve this , double press shift which allows to search files and then search for Vim actions. Here, you should see Vim enabled is ticked. Uncheck that option to disable and your cursor becomes normal.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

1. android studio preferences
2. search for "use block caret"
3. uncheck it

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or
<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
or if all else fails, try exiting, and restarting Android Studio

Comment: what's the meaning ?